# Error "No main mesh" when export to p3d format

Tags: export, error

I am new to Blender and when I try to export my project to p3d format (I installed the add-on from [here](https://github.com/wurunduk/blender-p3d-import-export)) I get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When export project just select "Force main mesh"